# Scala Jar: Read Databricks secrets using DBUtils

Tags: scala, jar, nullpointerexception, databricks, dbutils

Im trying to run Scala jar in databricks cluster, getting `HiveException: Unable to execute method public java.lang.String udfDecrypt.evaluate(java.lang.String) with arguments {***gAAAAABgKpJSbxtLkTiED3B3bMGEV0pdgMuE4km85NWJQ4Rh9zzV9pW1TN-wnfTx0-sikuAYGIN6vnIoFBacFT3MRcF5W7dBmeNNaRZbzC69ij77R2LyB5Q=}:null Caused by: InvocationTargetException:  Caused by: NullPointerException:`

from below code while reading secret from databricks secret scope,

```
import com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder.dbutils
```

```
val DecryptionKey: String = dbutils.secrets.get("secretDatabricks","PIIDecryptionKey")
```

Please guide me if im doing anything wrong! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest to rotate this key...

Comment: Thanks @TomerShetah Could you please explain more

Comment: I mean that if gAAAAABgKpJSbxtLkTiED3B3bMGEV0pdgMuE4km85NWJQ4Rh9zzV9pW1TN-wnfTx0-sikuAYGIN6vnIoFBacFT3MRcF5W7dBmeNNaRZbzC69ij77R2LyB5Q= is a real key you are using, make sure to invalidate it.

Comment: Are "secretDatabricks", and "PIIDecryptionKey" the correct scope and key?

Comment: @TomerShetah,  yes, scope and keyname is correct. "gAAAAABgKpJSbxtLkTiED3B3bMGEV0pdgMuE4km85NWJQ4Rh9zzV9pW1TN-wnfTx0-sikuAYGIN6vnIoFBacFT3MRcF5W7dBmeNNaRZbzC69ij77R2LyB5Q= " this is sample data im trying to decryption

Comment: ref. https://databricks.com/notebooks/enforcing-column-level-encryption.html